# Reading encoded data using muxing in ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to read an encoded video using ffmpeg c++. When I try to build my code error appears as identifier options is undefined. But it is already defined as  `AVDictionary *options = NULL`.

What is wrong with my code?

```
void CFfmpegmethods::VideoRead(){

    const char *url = "H:/Sanduni_projects/ad_2.mp4";

    AVFormatContext *s = NULL;
    int ret = avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret < 0)
        abort();

    avformat_find_stream_info(s, &options);

    AVDictionary *options = NULL;

    av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "640x480", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "pixel_format", "rgb24", 0);

    if (avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, &options) < 0){
        abort();
    }

    av_dict_free(&options);

    AVDictionaryEntry *e;

    if (e = av_dict_get(options, "", NULL, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Option %s not recognized by the demuxer.\n", e->key);
        abort();
    }

    avformat_close_input(&s);
}
```

Comment: Now the problem is abort() is called since avformat_open_input gives a minus value. Can someone explain why is that? Is it a problem of the file type that I try to open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I forgot to add av_register_all() at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out `about()` brought declaration of `options` variable into the scope of `if`, so your code does this:

```
if (ret < 0)
{
    //abort();

    AVDictionary *options = NULL;
}
```

It is a good idea to always open a new {} after branching to avoid such problems:

```
if (ret < 0)
{
    //abort(); // now commenting this line does not make scope to change
}
AVDictionary *options = NULL;
```

Comment: commenting the abort() was a mistake. I just did it for a testing purpose. Now it has corrected.

Comment: Now this error appears
Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEE2DD4DE4 (avformat-57.dll) in EncodedDetection.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000020.